# Win10 Command Prompt + Batch Files - Permissions Manipulation with takeown and icacls. Need guidance

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, batch-file

I am trying to build an assortment of batch files that control permissions on files and folders via right click context menu. I know there are existing solutions out there but I am trying to code it myself.

Ideally I'd like the following separate commands:

- Take Ownership of a Directory (Recursive)
- Take Ownership of a File
- Set Owner to Current User
- Set Owner to Administrators
- Set Owner to TrustedInstaller

Right now I'm focused on the Take Ownership functions. My problem is that I don't know the "Proper" way to Take Ownership of a directory and all its files and sub-directories.

There are various implementations scattered around the internet that "work", but the resulting permissions look really polluted with a lot of duplicate entries.

The "Take Ownership" commands floating around are all basically this:

`cmd.exe /c takeown /f "%~1" /r /d Y && icacls "%~1" /grant *S-1-3-4:F /t /c /l /q`

But when I run that command on a directory located in Program Files, this is what I get:

[image: Duplicate Permission Entries]

I don't know about you, but I think the access list looks pretty ugly/polluted. There are duplicates for every entry.

So I started messing with the `/inheritance:d` flag, which disables inheritance and copies the ACEs:

`cmd.exe /c takeown /r /d Y /f "%~1" && icacls "%~1" /inheritance:d /grant *S-1-3-4:(OI)(CI)F /T /C /L /Q`
`icacls "%~1" /grant administrators:(OI)(CI)F /T /C /L /Q`

This command transfers ownership to the current user recursively, disables inheritance, grants the current user and Administrators full access for "This folder, subfolders, and files." `(OI)(CI)`

This is what I get now:

[image: Cleaner ACLs]

The access list looks a lot cleaner, but there is no inheritance.

I guess my questions are:

1. When taking ownership of a folder recursively, should I keep inheritance enabled?
2. How do I de-duplicate permission entries correctly, hopefully without completely disabling inheritance?
3. Should I be using iCACLS `/grant:r` to replace permissions?
4. Am I over-thinking things?!

Really appreciate any input on this.

Comment: "Am I over-thinking things?!" - Yes.

Comment: @harrymc :( Sorry if my question is a bit trivial. Even though it's a small problem to solve, I'd like to know if there is a Right Way™

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would always keep the inhertance. Instead of icacls I would use PowerShell:
Copy permissions:

Get-ACL C:\Shared | Set-Acl C:\Shared1

Before you set permissions on the multiple files and folders, it is always recommended that you use the -WhatIf parameter to know on which file or folder permissions are being applied. lthough Set-ACL works fine, it's a clunky bit of code that isn't very 'powershelly'. As tfl mentioned, there's an external module called NTFSSecurity that makes this a lot easier: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.4

Powershell

## List folder ACLs and their current inheritance

```
Get-Item .\Data -Recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} | Get-NTFSAccess | select fullname,inheritanceenabled
```

To change the permissions you would need to change the inherance otherwise you can't modify it.
But with $permissions = Get-Acl, you can save it in a variable and reapply if needed, or export to an csv and so on.
https://thesleepyadmins.com/2020/04/28/export-folder-permission-using-powershell/

I always recommend it to export it first, and then changing, because you can restore if you make a mistake.